# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: asp.net, query-string, rad-controls

I have Default.aspx and Upload.aspx.
I'm passing Id through query string to `default.aspx`(`like:http://localhost:3081/default.aspx?Id=1752`).In default page i have a link button to open the upload.aspx to upload file.When i use the `Request.QueryString["Id"]` in upload.aspx,it is showiing error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".I'm dealing with RadControls.
To open when i click a link(`OnClientClick="return ShowAddFeedBackForm()"`) i have code like:

```
<script>
function ShowAddFeedBackForm() {
            window.radopen("Upload.aspx", "UserListDialog");
           return false;
    }
</script>
```

I'm using detailsview in upload page with a textbox and a fileupload control.

**code to bind when a file upload in upload.aspx**

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
string qString = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString();
       if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
       {

           //string qString = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString();
           //int Projectid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ProjectId"]);
           ProTrakEntities objEntity = new ProTrakEntities();
           TextBox txtTitle = DetailsView1.FindControl("txtTask") as TextBox;
           //RadComboBox cmbStatus = DetailsView1.FindControl("cmbStatus") as RadComboBox;
           //var id = (from project in objEntity.Projects where project.ProjectId == Projectid select project).First();
           RadComboBox cmbTaskType = DetailsView1.FindControl("cmbTasktype") as RadComboBox;
           //RadComboBox cmbTaskPriorty = DetailsView1.FindControl("cmbPriority") as RadComboBox;

           string Description = (DetailsView1.FindControl("RadEditor1") as RadEditor).Content;



           var guid = (from g in objEntity.Projects where g.ProjectGuid == qString select g).First();
           int pID = Convert.ToInt32(guid.ProjectId);

           ProjectFeedback objResource = new ProjectFeedback();
           objResource.ProjectId = pID;
           objResource.Subject = txtTitle.Text;
           objResource.Body = Description;
           objResource.CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
           objResource.FeedbackType = cmbTaskType.SelectedItem.Text;
           objEntity.AddToProjectFeedbacks(objResource);
           objEntity.SaveChanges();

           DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);
           ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "mykey", "CloseAndRebind('navigateToInserted');", true);


       }

}
```

Getting error at querystring statement-"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: It would be helpful to insert the stack trace from the error.

Comment: thank you fro your response sir.i didn't get you what is inserting fro stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace is the long list of methods listed in the exception when it tells you that Object reference is not set to an instace of an object.  There is usually a list of methods called that eventually lead to the method that generated the error being produced.

Comment: See the answer I just posted where I explain exactly what you need to do to get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

The query string is not inherited when you open a new page. You have to include the id in the URL, i.e. `Upload.aspx?id=1752`.

#### Edit:

A simple solution would be to just copy the search part of the page URL:

```
window.radopen("Upload.aspx" + document.location.search, "UserListDialog");
```

However, typically you would use the id value that you picked up from the query string in the server side code and generate client code to use it.

Comment: thank you for your response sir.How can we define like that?Because the Upload.aspx will be open when we click a link button.If we pass it any way,How can it be work when pass different Id in querystring next time.

Comment: Exactly.  Most likely, the error is here:
`string qString = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString();`

Since QueryString["Id"] is returning null, the exception is thrown on .ToString().

Comment: @user: You're obviously not going to hard-code an ID.  You're obviously going to have to get the ID from the query string of the page you're calling your window from.

Comment: I agree this is most likely the place the error was generated.  As you can see this error could come from a large number of places.  It would be wise to test your objects for nullness before using them.

Comment: yes sir,oscilatingcretin, i'm getting error at querystring statement.Means i was null.So how can get the Id in uploadpage which was passed as querystring while calling default page?

Comment: @user872998: See answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if I had to guess I would question whether the window object has been instantiated at the time you call radopen in the script section of your page.  You should put a msgbox before the call window.radopen() call to print the contents of the window object if it is null that is your problem otherwise this will take more digging.  Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I also noted that if the guid query returns no results the call to .First() will cause this error as well.  Just another place to check while researching the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is one last place I see that could also throw this error if the objEntities failed to construct and returned a null reference then any call to the properties of the object will generate this error (i.e objEntitiey.Projects):

```
 ProTrakEntities objEntity = new ProTrakEntities();  
 var guid = (from g in objEntity.Projects where g.ProjectGuid == qString select g).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because, as the other answerer said, you need to pass the ID to the RadWindow since the RadWindow doesn't know anything about the page that called it.  You're getting a null reference exception because the window can't find the query string, so it's throwing an exception when you try to reference .ToString().

To get it to work, make your Javascript function like this:

```
function ShowAddFeedBackForm(Id) {
    window.radopen(String.format("Upload.aspx?Id={0}", Id), "UserListDialog");
    return false;
}
```

In the codebehind Page_Load event of your base page (ie, the page that is opening the window), put this:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    Button.OnClientClick = string.Format("javascript:return ShowAddFeedBackForm({0});", Request.QueryString["Id"]);
```

Of course, `Button` should be the ID of the button as it is on your page.

Comment: I just made a correction to the `Id` parameter's casing.  In the javascript function, it was `id`, but should have been `Id`.

Comment: how can we pass the ID which was coming from default page to ShowAddFeedBackForm(Id).we get the id in codebehind of defaultpage with querystring["Id"].The Id should be available in default,but upload page is called when we click a linkbutton in default page.

Comment: I made an edit to to remove ambiguity.  By codebehind, I am talking about the codebehind of the base page, not the page opened in the RadWindow.

Comment: Yes sir,I tried i'm getting value in request.querystring[],but when we use this in string.format placeholder,it was showing the same,object reference not set to an instance.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where you're setting the .OnClientClick property.  Step over it and make sure the Javascript is correct.  Also make sure you're not overwriting it elsewhere in your code.  To be safe, remove the OnClientClick from the button's markup.

Comment: i verified sir,but same error.I think your replies may be better useful for me.

Comment: Did you edit your Javascript function like I showed you above?  I am not really sure how much more I can help, though.

Comment: And you fixed the casing issue of the Id that I previously mentioned?

Comment: in page load:LinkButton lnkAddFeedback = (LinkButton)RadGrid2.FindControl("lnkAddFeedback");
                lnkAddFeedback.OnClientClick = String.Format("javascript:return ShowAddFeedBackForm({0});",Request.QueryString["Id"]);.I did as you told,but causing the same issue.

Comment: java script as:function ShowAddFeedBackForm(Id) {
window.radopen(String.Format("Upload.aspx?Id={0}",Id), "UserListDialog");
            return false;
        }

Comment: Is your RadGrid bound with a collection of objects that have an Id property?

Comment: @user872998 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2808/discussion-between-oscilatingcretin-and-user872998)

Comment: yes sir: <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" runat="server" PageSize="5" Skin="Default" AllowPaging="True"
                        OnItemDataBound="RadGrid2_ItemDataBound" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid2_NeedDataSource"  AllowSorting="true" ShowFooter="true"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="50%" GridLines="None" OnItemCreated="RadGrid2_ItemCreated">